# Display value from a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pdf

I am trying to create a 2D array to search for a value based on width and projection, I am stuck at this point.

The code should read two fields Width and projection as the search. Then display in a third field.

```
var width = this.getField("Width").value;
var projection = this.getField("projection").value;
const table = [

{ width: 2000, projections: [{ size: 200, price: 499}, { size: 400, price: 1499}]},
{ width: 3000, projections: [{ size: 200, price: 999}, { size: 400, price: 1999}]},
];

// return the relevant row based on the awning width
const projections = table.filter(function(item) {
return item.width == (Math.ceil(width/1000)*1000);
}).map(function(width) { return width.projections });

// take this result and filter by projection size
const price = projections[0].filter(function(projection) {
return projection.size == projection;
})[0];

event.value = price.price;
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Provide what result you are expecting from the array as an example

Comment: If the user typed in say 2200 for the width and  275 for projection the price should read 499